# IPSEC - Remote Access Clients, Tunnel or Transport Mode?

Tags: ipsec

I understand that transport mode encrypts only the payload.

Do IPSec clients such as Cisco's AnyConnect and/or Cisco VPN Client use transport mode?  Or do these clients and others like them use tunnel mode?

Comment: Does this help: http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/870-ipsec-modes.html

Comment: Not sure cuz it says RDP uses transport mode however [this](https://security.berkeley.edu/content/securing-remote-desktop-system-administrators) article seems to say otherwise.

Comment: is RDP an important consideration for you, or do you doubt the article because it is not accurate? (trying to get a sense of your requirements)

Comment: Just trying to understand a real world use of transport mode, i.e., the name of software that utilizes it.

Answer (score 2):

Client-side VPNs (AnyConnect, RDP) use transport mode because they set up end-to-end or end-to-site encryption. They do not rely on any other security infrastructure to create and maintain the tunnel.

Tunnel mode is most often done between VPN gateways (routers) that maintain the tunnel without needing to install or configure the clients.

Some clients can make use of VPN gateways as well, but when your client is "all alone", they use transport mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24150/discussion-between-schroeder-and-ron-royston).

Answer (score -1):

AnyConnect and Cisco VPN Client use tunnel mode, as the communication is actually between the initiator (VPN client) and devices *behind* the VPN gateway.

Comment: this is true only in the case where you are connecting to a device behind a VPN gateway